# How to ask about manager's current illness condition?

Tags: communication, colleagues

My manager has been suffering from chickenpox since early last week and plans to come back to the office tomorrow.

What is the best way **via chat** to ask him whether he has fully recovered from his chickenpox?

I have never had chickenpox and don't remember if I was vaccinated or not, so I  am very concerned.

Comment: What are you going to go based on the answer?

Comment: Why the negative reception on this? I get that this needs a rewrite but the main question seems clear and on-topic, even if the answer might not be what the OP is looking for.

Comment: @jcm Agreed, I don't see ethics question either.

Comment: Not only manager, and chicken pox. Some of my colleagues come to work, although they still ill :(

Comment: Sounds like you should go get vaccinated, regardless of what you do in this situation.

Comment: @Kat vaccine can have side effects that would mean time off work, it's not always as simple as having a shot and back to normal.

Comment: @Kilisi it doesn't sound like OP has serious issues with vaccines in general. Maybe getting it today isn't reasonable, but finding an opportunity in the near future is a good idea. Better to have some possible side effects from a vaccine at a time of your choosing than to be unexpectedly infected with the chicken pox.

Comment: @Kat sounds reasonable, sometimes not that easy to  accomplish as a busy adult... but I agree he should get vaccinated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What is the best way via chat to ask him whether he has fully
>   recovered from his chickenpox?

Just be friendly and express concern for your manager's health.

Just ask something like "Hi. How are you feeling? Fully recovered? I heard that you might be coming back to work later this week?"

You'll likely get a response on the order of "Thanks. My doctor says that I won't be contagious and I can go back tomorrow."

That said, just stay away from your manager for a few days when he returns. The virus is not as easily spread as most. It can be spread through coughing and sneezing, but is mostly spread by contact.

If necessary, make a joke about it when he returns. "Ugh! I never got the vaccine and I'm not getting near you!" when said with a smile and a laugh won't be offensive.

Answer (score 14):

Chickenpox is contagious 2 days before the "pox" are showing and until the pox are completly dry.

Don't ask, if you see your boss with "pox" that still look like they're filled with liquid, stay away from him.

Comment: Difficult tell what they look like unless the manager is up close, which is *too* close. The manager should stay out of the office until a doctor says so as the manager may not know the state of his condition.

Comment: If I were a manager, I wouldn't come to work if I looked like a 5-year old had fun with a red marker when I was asleep. :-)

Answer (score 11):

If you feel the need to ask because you don't trust them to come back in a non contagious situation. Then just ask him politely, mention you have never had chicken pox so you're a bit concerned.

Don't take chances with your health. As your manager he/she shouldn't be taking this the wrong way. It hurts the team if a staff member becomes ill.

Chicken pox can be very dangerous in adults, particularly males. In rare cases life threatening if there are complications.

Comment: The manager might be offended, in that you're implying that they're not smart or responsible enough to wait until they're not contagious any more before returning to work.

Comment: @Dukeling hence my first sentence. Normally you would trust them, but I have had some absolute idiot managers and if it came to a choice between my health and them getting mildly offended, I'd choose my health every time. Chicken pox can be very dangerous in adults, particularly males.

Comment: @Dukeling Manager does not equal smart, or courteous to ones employees.

Comment: Not to mention that lots of people have this crazy "must come to work even when sick or be considered a weakling" attitude, so it's not at all unusual for sick people to show up for office in some cultures.

Comment: @Dukeling I'm reading this question to mean that the OP really doesn't trust the manager to be that responsible, and while they want to minimise the risk of causing offense, it's a lower priority than minimising the risk of catching chickenpox.

Comment: can you get vaccinated now ?

Comment: @Neuromancer you can get vaccinated any time, but the vaccine has side effects which can last a month. Catching chickenpox is worse though, it can be dangerous, and can lead to shingles later in life which is very nasty.